# Jupyter kernel fails to connect *only* without an internet connection

Tags: python, windows, kernel, jupyter, conda

I'm interested in being able to work on a Notebook in transit during a future busy stretch of travel, where I know I will not have an internet connection for several hours on end. I asked a [similar question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76551122/running-py-script-in-vscode-with-no-internet-connection) not long ago  regarding just plain `.py` files, which was much  more straight forward, however my foray into trying to sort this out with Jupyter notebooks has inspired me to ask as a dedicated question.

The part that's particularly bothering me is that everywhere I've read (including a commented answer in *my own* previously asked question) suggests that **Notebooks should be fully workable without an internet connection (??)** - obviously assuming there is no explicit dependency for it in my code and all required packages have already been installed ahead of time.

Here is what I've done/tried thus far:

1. Fresh Anaconda install by first following [official Full Uninstall instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/) before reinstalling. Cut laptop Wifi connection (W10 Airplane Mode). Open Anaconda Prompt and execute `jupyter notebook`. From Home Page in Notebook http://localhost:8888/tree : New > Notebook > Python 3 (ipykernel). Attempt to execute cell `print('hello')`. Kernel is always "Busy" and never "Idle" at any point in this process, causing the extended `In [*]:` cell state. After some amount of time, I'm thrown the "A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration." error.
2. Using a fresh environment created [as per official conda documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) `conda create --name myenv`. Of course this is followed by `conda activate myenv` and then `conda install jupyter` to ensure correct dependencies exist in `myenv`. Repeat process as in 1. Same result.
3. Try repeating both 1. and 2. in different IDEs where I have no trouble connecting to kernel *with* an internet connection. Outside from the native Notebook interface, I have tried with: Jupyter Lab, VSCode, Spyder Notebook. All the same behaviour: the kernel connects and the `print('hello')` cell executes no problem if I have an internet connection. Timeout//failed cell run/`In [*]` behaviour if Notebook is launched with no internet connection.

Some other points to note:

- I definitely have `ipykernel` installed in all environments I've tried. Internet connection or not, from either `base` or `myenv` I am able to start an `ipython` instance from the Anaconda Prompt.
- This is likely related to the previous point, however the *closest* workaround I have found is to use `.py` files in Spyder with the interactive `# %%` "cells", which run in their IPython "console" style IDE. This is the only way that I have been able to get Notebook-type behaviour with no internet connection at any point in the process. I should note that this takes ages to first initialize, but once it's going it works. I'm aware VSCode has a similar ability to run the psueudo `# %%` cells, but here I can't get a "cell" to run without internet, whereas in Spyder I can.
- In all of these scenarios/IDEs, the kernel **will continue to run** if it is *first* initialized with an internet connection. This is promising, but obviously is not a good solution because I am not able to successfully restart the kernel after the internet connection has been cut off.

To me, all signs point to there being some kind of issue with kernel initialization in whichever `conda` env I try this in. The other major troubleshooting step I've tried is [Downgrading tornado](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5024#issuecomment-653618109), but to no avail.

I should end by saying my preference is to use VSCode, but the problem clearly reaches beyond an IDE-specific issue.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Is there any relevant output in the cmd window in which you ran `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller [This](https://imgur.com/Ztl0aMN) is basically what I get in the cmd window throughout the whole attempting to connect process (the Nudge count at the bottom increases by 10 until it gets to 50)

Comment: @Wayne Good suggestion - I thought of that as well. Unfortunately, the problem persists whether it's simply "No Internet Connection" (i.e. wifi on and not connected to any network) or "Airplane Mode"

Comment: Dang. Would you be willing to try [JupyterLab Desktop](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-2022-recap-28bdf00205c6)? It would preclude VSCode but maybe allows the minimum what you need here.

Comment: @Wayne Unfortunately that doesn't do the trick either. Like I said, it's essentially any IDE where I try to run a .ipynb Notebook where no matter what I do, the kernel fails to initialize without an internet connection

Comment: I should probably have referenced [this advice](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-cannot-run-in-offline-mode/15587/2?u=fomightez) below the OP for running JupyterLab 'offline'. Since the underlying tech for all current JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+ releases is inline with JupyterLab or JupyterLab-related components, that post is now potentially more pertinent in a way.