# VSCode Python Jupyter kernel timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm getting this error while trying to run my .ipynb files using VSCode:
'Failed to start the Kernel.
Unable to start Kernel 'Python 3.11.4' due to a timeout waiting for the ports to get used.'

Python 3.11.4, Python, Pylance and Jupyter extensions and required packages like ipykernel are installed and up to date.
It was working a few hours ago and I don't know what's wrong right now. I can still run my older notebook files but not the new ones.

In the logs, I'm seeing this error:
'Error: Unable to start Kernel 'Python 3.11.4' due to a timeout waiting for the ports to get used.'

Tried reinstalling VSCode, extensions, Python interpreter and packages like ipykernel but it did not fix the issue.
Tried running with and without VPN but it also did not help.

What can I do?

Edit: I figured out that this error occures only in a specific folder. It even works in the subfolders of it. I still have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: related error message at https://stackoverflow.com/q/76551122/11107541. Does that Q&A help you at all?

Comment: This can be due to the tornado version. Ensure that it is greater than 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Then I opened a terminal in VS Code and I was able to run the notebook.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35807718)

Answer (score -2):

> due to a timeout waiting for the ports to get used.

1. Try to restart your computer.
2. Check if there is a firewall blocking the connection.
3. Check if there are any other processes running that might be using
   the required ports.

Comment: I tried restarting multiple times and also tried turning firewall off, but did not work either.

Comment: @Supermani Are you using jupyter locally or remotely?

Comment: I'm using it locally.

Comment: @Supermani Have you tried to choose the python interpreter and rechosen the jupyter kernl?

Comment: Yes I chose Python environments >> Python 3.11.4. The error only occurs in a specific folder and does not occur in other folders.

Comment: Could you please try creating a new virtual environment for that folder and install the required packages in the new environment. You can use the `venv` module to create a new virtual environment, activate it, and install the required packages using `pip`.

Comment: This kind of junk answer is exactly why I hate answers.microsoft.com. Entirely useless generic troubleshooting steps, and "diplomatically verbose" language. Exact opposite of being concise.